# Route 53 Amazon Aws - Check service (Solr) health in my ec2 instance

Tags: solr, amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

I have the apache solr running in my instance ec2 (port:8983).

Is it possible, create a health check in Route53 to monitorize Solr?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible.  The port and path of Route 53 health checks is fully configurable, so you can create one pointing to eg. your-ec2-instance:8983/admin/ping

There are a few things you'd have to setup:

- your ec2 instance needs to be reachable from the [IP addresses used by Route 53 healthcheckers](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/dns-failover-router-firewall-rules.html)
- apache solr needs a [URL that can be used to determine if it's healthy](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/dns-failover-determining-health-of-endpoints.html).  A good way of doing this is with solr's [ping request handler](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_1_0/solr-core/org/apache/solr/handler/PingRequestHandler.html)

Full disclosure - I work for Route 53